# using scipy.integrate.odeint, set value of x to constant if an event occurs

Tags: python, scipy, ode, hybrid

I am using scipy.integrate.odeint to solve a set of ODEs for two variables x and y. In the func(x,y,t) (which defines odes and returns dx/dt and dy/dt), I am also checking if an event 'EVENT1' has occured. If the 'EVENT1' occurs, I don't want to use the ODEs, instead I want to set x= x0 and y = y0, where, x0 and y0 are constants. And at next instance again start using ODEs until next time 'EVENT1' occurs. 
I am not able to understand how to do that.

Comment: You should not do that. Event handling should be part of the solver, not of the ODE function. The ODE function should be as smooth as the order of the solver (differentiable for Euler, 5-times differentiable for dopri5). This excludes jumps and kinks in the ODE function.